# Trigger views with multiple ibeacons

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ibeacon, clregion

I'm developing an app for iPad that uses more than one beacon and I need to show a view when I enter its region,then, when I'm near a beacon and far from the other one, I need the first one to be closed and open the second one.

My code is this:

```
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [beacons lastObject];


    SectionViewController *sectionView = [[SectionViewController alloc] init];
    Sections2ViewController *sectionView2 = [[Sections2ViewController alloc] init];

    if ((beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) && viewShown == NO && beacon.accuracy != -1.000000) {

        if ((beacon.minor.integerValue != actualSection) && actualSection != 0) {
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
            actualSection = 0;
            NSLog(@"View Out");
        }

        if (beacon.minor.integerValue  == 1) {
            [self presentViewController:sectionView animated:NO completion:nil];
            sectionView.section = 1;
            actualSection = 1;
            sectionView.lbl_name.text = self.lbl_name.text;
            NSLog(@"View In: 1");
            viewShown = YES;
        }else if (beacon.minor.integerValue == 2){
            [self presentViewController:sectionView2 animated:NO completion:nil];
            sectionView.section = 2;
            actualSection = 2;
            NSLog(@"View In: 2");
            viewShown = YES;
        }
    }else if ((beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear || beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar) && viewShown == YES && beacon.accuracy != -1.000000){
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
        viewShown = NO;
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Unknown Distance");
    }

    NSLog(@"\nUUID: %@\nProximity:%ld\nMajor:%@\nMinor:%@\nAccuracy:%f\nRSSI:%ld\nSection: %ld", beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString, beacon.proximity, beacon.major, beacon.minor, beacon.accuracy, (long)beacon.rssi, (long)self.section);
}
```

- sectionView and SectionView2 are the views i want to show.
- I use viewShown to know if a view is presented or i'm in the
  mainView.
- actualSection is to know where im I.

The problem is that if I use only 1 beacon it works perfect but when I'm doing it with 2 the app doesn't detect both of them and its hard to show the correctView.

I'm trying it now but the app only detects 1 beacon and im using the same UUID on both of them and only changing minor value.

I'm using ios 7.0.4 on my iPad Mini retina now, but I'll update to iOS 7.1 soon - is it a problem?

---

Solved:

```
    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)initRegion {
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:@"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"com.devfright.myRegion"];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Beacon Found");
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Left Region");
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [beacons lastObject];

    //Search for the closest and show the view
    for (int i=0; i<beacons.count; i++) {
        beacon = beacons[i];

        if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"Unknown Proximity");
        } else if ((beacon.proximity == CLProximityImmediate) && viewShown == NO && beacon.accuracy != -1.000000) {
            if ([beacon.minor.stringValue  isEqual: @"1"]) {
                actualSection = 1;
                [self immediateDetection];
            }else if ([beacon.minor.stringValue  isEqual: @"2"]){
                actualSection = 2;
                [self immediateDetection];
            }else if ([beacon.minor.stringValue  isEqual: @"3"]){
                actualSection = 3;
                [self immediateDetection];
            }else if ([beacon.minor.stringValue  isEqual: @"4"]){
                actualSection = 4;
                [self immediateDetection];
            }
        } else if ((beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear || beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar) && viewShown == YES && beacon.accuracy != -1.000000) {
            if (beacon.minor.integerValue == actualSection) {
                [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
                actualSection = 0;
                viewShown = NO;
            }
        } else if (beacon.proximity == CLProximityFar) {
            NSLog(@"Far");
        }
    }
}
- (void)immediateDetection
{
    viewShown = YES;
    if (self.presentedViewController)
    {
        return;
    }
    if (actualSection == 1) {
        SectionViewController *sectionView = [[SectionViewController alloc] init];
        sectionView.section = 1;
        [self presentViewController:sectionView animated:NO completion:nil];
        sectionView.lbl_name.text = self.lbl_name.text;
    }else if (actualSection == 2){
        SectionViewController *sectionView = [[SectionViewController alloc] init];
        sectionView.section = 2;
        [self presentViewController:sectionView animated:NO completion:nil];
        sectionView.lbl_name.text = self.lbl_name.text;
    }
}
```

Now this is correct and detect the close one. Thanks

Comment: You should share the code you use to start ranging beacons, there might be an issue there.

Comment: Also,  [[SectionViewController alloc] init];  strange way to instantiate a controller, have you overridden the init method?

Comment: I've solved it, with the code below the first